# Sumproduct of 2 arrays with Criteria on Each

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am trying to create a conditional sumproduct formula across two different arrays of data. What I would like to be able to do is to use sumproduct to multiply ranges of cells based on criteria in both arrays. Here is the sample data:

[image]

So, for example, if I choose "Online" as my option from both arrays, a non dynamic form would be this:

=sumproduct(B2:M2,B8:M8)

which yields 93.14%, my desired result.

However, I want to make that dynamic and to be able to select in the formula which "Seasonality" or which "Ramp Curve" I want to multiply in the formula.

Is there a form of sumproduct that will do this for me? To use the example above of "Online," the best I can come up with is (which does not work):

=sumproduct((B2:M4*(A2:A4=A16)),(B8:M9*(A8:A9=A16)))

where A16 is a cell that contains "Online."

I would appreciate any help here, thank you!

Link:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1VIg4AWGHeUc5CM-kkS6kmoTk7Hv9AfVk/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Mind sharing a copy of your sheet for us to look at?

Comment: I would love to! What is the best way to do that? A google sheet?

Comment: Yeah, make a copy, get a shareable link, edit it into your question.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1VIg4AWGHeUc5CM-kkS6kmoTk7Hv9AfVk/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with the formula is that you are trying to sum arrays with different sizes. Equalize the sizes and the problem will be solved.

```
=sumproduct((B2:M4*(A2:A4=A16)),(B8:M10*(A8:A10=A16)))
```

[image]